# Can I apply for a UK tourist visa while in Italy as a Dominican citizen?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, italy

I am a Dominican citizen currently in Italy on a 3-month Schengen Visa.

I want to visit the UK for tourism.

Can I apply for a UK Standard Visitor Visa for tourism purposes while in Italy as a Dominican citizen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Access UK](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa) online visa application service, but you will still need to visit the Visa Application Centre in Rome.

The [UK Visa and Immigration guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy) on this is quite clear:

> **1. Applications for short-term visas and EEA family permits**
>
> You can make applications for a visit visa, a short-term study visa or EEA family permit in any visa application centre, British diplomatic mission or consular post overseas where entry clearance applications are accepted.
>
> You should be present legally in the country or territory you’re applying from.